# error: no such partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue

i mistakenly deleted my ubuntu and i also have windows 10 on my pc, now when i start my computer i see a grub rescue prompt. I have tried the set root and set prefix and insmod normal command and it didn't work, i have also tried the steps from this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and it also didn't work but it gave me a url that i can paste in a forum for help, so here it is http://paste2.org/
I want my ubuntu back with all the files in it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you give more explanation on what you did to delete ubuntu?  Depending on the case, recovery may be possible or not.

Comment: i was trying to expand a volume in an eternal hdd connected to my computer in windows 10 and i mistakenly expanded my local disk causing my ubuntu to be deleted